# Font not rendering from one URL but fine on other sites

Tags: css, font-face

I have 7 websites (different domains on one shared hosting account) all sharing the same CSS file, all of them display 3 fonts correctly except one URL, and it is just one font that doesn't display, I am loading 3 custom fonts, 2 are fine, 1 not, and they are all loaded the same way.

Any idea what's happening?

Here is the problem site ... http://www.theridgesresort.com/

Here is a site that works ... http://www.fontanavillage.com/

Please view the sites at less than 750 pixels wide, it is just the mobile style. Look at the big yellow buttons.

Comment: it might help if we know what site it is so we can see how you inputted the css

Comment: can you just copy what you wrote in your css and place it here?

Comment: Hi Kieth, I added the links and a better explanation to the original post. Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

- The paths are all correct. Maybe the one site-structure has submaps
  etc. You  can use relative paths (../)
- Check for spelling mistakes

I see in your stylesheet (fonts.css) a reference to this, yet there is no folder there with the font.

```
src: url('http://www.anchorsouthmanagement.com/assets/css/copperplate_bold/Copperplate-Bold-webfont.eot');
```

I guess the problem is with loading the different stylesheet on mobile. This is what the console spits out:

[image]

Comment: Jan, I am loading the styles from another URL and using a full path "http://www.anchorsouthmanagement.com/assets/css/responsive-overrides-2.css". -- Thanks for helping.

Please tke another look at my original post, I edited it to include links and better explanation.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? I still wonder why it works on all the other fonts and all the other sites. Very strange.

Comment: As the console says, it seems like your are trying to load some stylesheets from another website. Your webhost has some basic security-settings that prevents this. CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) is disabled. I would suggest placing the stylesheet on the same server as the website.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied the same path from the correct site to the other and it works for me:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'copperplate_boldcondensed';
src: url('copperplate_boldcondensed/Copperplate-BoldCond-webfont.eot');
src: url('copperplate_boldcondensed/Copperplate-BoldCond-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('copperplate_boldcondensed/Copperplate-BoldCond-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('copperplate_boldcondensed/Copperplate-BoldCond-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('copperplate_boldcondensed/Copperplate-BoldCond-webfont.svg#copperplate_gothic_boldRg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: Keith, you solved the problem. Thanks. I did not realize I was using two different fonts.css files. Thanks!